# How to pass parameters using Query string in a Soap web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

This is my first web service, written using .NET 4.6.

I'm using `System.Web.Services.WebService`.

How can I pass parameter in query string to a web service ?

If I call the URL: `http://localhost:11111/myWebService.asmx/GetWorldById`  and try to pass also parameters like

http://localhost:111/myWebService.asmx/GetWorldById?worldid=1

I got error: `Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetWorldById'`

This is my code

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetWorldById(int worldid)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection db = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", db);
            MySqlDataReader dr;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE worldid='" + param1+ "'";
            db.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                PopulateListFromDataReader(dr);

            }


        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return (js.Serialize(worldsList));
    }
```

Comment: Soap does not use url parameters, it uses xml payloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always read parameters from the requests

int worldid = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request[nameof(worldid)]);

but you need a post request anyway.